# ListBox команда при выделении ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как можно при нажатии ListBoxItem выполнить команду открытия нового окна.(MVVM) ListBox заполняется через ItemSource. XAML разметка такая:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox11" MaxHeight="0" 
                     Style="{StaticResource MenuListBox}" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentItemList}" 
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemMenu}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListBox11 , Path=SelectedValue}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ListBox>
```

А вот как код написать не имею представления.

Model: `public class MenuItemModel { public bool Indicator { get; set; } public string Icon { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } }`

VM: `public List MenuItemList { get; set; }
        public List DocumentItemList { get; set; }

```
    public MenuItemViewModel()
    {
        MenuItemList = new List<MenuItemModel>
        {
            new MenuItemModel
            {
                Indicator = true,
                Icon = "\uf0e7",
                Name = "текст",
            },
            new MenuItemModel
            {
                Indicator = false,
                Icon = "\uf200",
                Name = "текст",
            },
            new MenuItemModel
            {
                Indicator = false,
                Icon = "\uf15c",
                Name = "текст",
            }
        };

        DocumentItemList = new List<MenuItemModel>
        {
            new MenuItemModel
            {
                Indicator = true,
                Icon = "\uf008",
                Name = "текст",
            },
            new MenuItemModel
            {
                Indicator = true,
                Icon = "\uf06b",
                Name = "текст",
            }
        };

        MyCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {

        });


    }

    #region Command

    public  ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }


    #endregion`
```

Comment: `А вот как код написать не имею представления.` код чего? Модели? Команды? Вьюмодели? Что у вас уже написано?

Comment: Если по простому, то вам триггеры и прочее не нужны, у вас уже есть привязка к SelectedItem, задайте в его Set нужное вам действие. Ну а так, делайте свойство типа ICommand, инициализируйте его, создавайте метод который будет вызываться и там делайте что надо.

Comment: Код Команды. Тип ICommand инициирован. а вот как правильно в команде это записать, не понимаю

Comment: вы приведите код моделей-вьюмоделей. Но вообще, как вам уже подсказали, вы можете из сетера вызывать команду

Comment: Model: '  public class MenuItemModel
    {
        public bool Indicator { get; set; }
        
        public string Icon { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    } '